# Collecting value of id_token_hint from url in AD B2C Custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm using [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) article to pass id_token_hint to my custom policy, my requirement is there any way to collect the value from the URL and pass that in the load URI of content definition

What I did for this is used claim resolver, but this is not working. If I hardcode some value instead of **{OAUTH-KV:id_token_hint}** then that works.

```xml
 <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <ContentDefinitionParameters>
        <Parameter Name="id_token_hint">{OAUTH-KV:id_token_hint}</Parameter>
      </ContentDefinitionParameters>
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
 </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Also defined a claimtype (think this is not required to pass the value to load uri)

```xml
<ClaimType Id="id_token_hint">
     <DisplayName>id_token_hint</DisplayName>
     <DataType>string</DataType>
     <UserHelpText>id token hint</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

But it is not sending the query string in my custom load URI in the content definition.

### Edit:

If I pass the same value with another parameter say **idtokenhint** that works, but **id_token_hint** is not working.

Comment: is it possible that id_token_hint is in form data and not in query string?
How are you getting id_token_hint?

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal I'm sending the URL to policies from azure function to the user's email for validating their email, in the URL appending **&id_token_hint=JWT token**. In the policy with the help of a technical profile, reading the values from the JWT token in id_token_hint query string

Comment: id_token_hint is a OIDC parameter, have you tried {OIDC:id_token_hint} instead?

Comment: @Jamie Yes, got a 500 error. Not remembering exact message

Comment: It’s reserved and won’t work in the claims resolver. Send any other param name and it will work.

Comment: @JasSuri Thanks for the confirmation, other parameters are working.